# How to get all dependency files for a program

Tags: go

I make a program in Go and after completing the code, if I want to run this code on other pc or VM, then it does not get all the dependency package files. How can I get all dependency files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `godep save` in your local pc where you complete your program. godep save collect all the dependency files for you. When you move to other pc, just copy the Godep folder with your code and it will solve your problems.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to some people, but I had to go dig this up.  Turns out you need to install the godep or dep package to Go.  The Github stie for this is here: https://github.com/tools/godep

Answer (score 274):

You can run `go get -d ./...` from a directory of your project to download all go-gettable dependencies.
Or copy all `src` subdirectory from your GOPATH to the destination machine.
`...` is a special pattern, tells to go down recursively.

Comment: If i need to run/ modify the code then it doesn't find packages.

Comment: I know i can get packages by go get <package> but it is so much time consuming and difficult when the program uses many packages.

Comment: -t will install also test dependencies

Comment: @AlbertoSchiabel `...` is a special pattern. It tells to go down recursively. I've updated an answer

Comment: Thanks @RoninDev! At first I was going to edit your answer to `./.`, because after having tried you command on my pc it kind of stuck (and now I know why, since recursive search of go files can be quite expensive), but then I realized it was better to ask first. Thanks!

Comment: It does not download the dependency of dependency? So me depends on A, but A depends on B, it seems B will not be downloaded automatically.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. Can someone explain to me why the hell go doesn't have a simple `go get_all` or something? This is the most basic command and there's no builtin to run it??

Answer (score 61):

Try

```
go list -f '{{ join .Imports "\n" }}'
```

or

```
go list -f '{{ join .Deps "\n" }}'
```

The second will list all subdependencies, the first only the directly imported packages.

Answer (score 53):

Below command works for me it downloads all the dependencies.

```
go get -u -v -f all
```

Comment: it takes a long time !!! it downloads packages that I never used in the project!

Answer (score 17):

It's `go mod download`. For more info check `go help mod`

Comment: this doesn't work, I'm not sure why this is upvoted so much

Answer (score 8):

If you are using module mode, you can try `go mod tidy`, as described [here](https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#synchronizing).

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Best way ever is get the list and iterate installing the packages, this works so fine:

```
while read l; do go get -v "$l"; done < <(go list -f '{{ join .Imports "\n" }}')
```